# Convert_tz function in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime, sql-convert

In MySQL there is function called `CONVERT_TZ(dt,from_tz,to_tz)` which converts one timezone to another timezone -[Reference](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_convert-tz)-.

I had used `CONVERT(datetime,SWITCHOFFSET(CONVERT(datetimeoffset,getdate()),'+05:30'))` this function is taking "+00:00" timezone offset which I don't wanted.

Is there any function in the SQL or any other way to convert timezone in SQL Server?

Comment: I think [this question](http://dba.stackexchange.com/q/39421/60970) can help you ;).

Comment: SQL Server **2008** and newer have [`SWITCHOFFSET`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb677244.aspx) and `DATETIMEOFFSET` datatype